# Rails Delayed Job Continuously Running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I created a batch email system for my website.  The problem I have, which is terrible, is it continuously sends out emails.  It seems the job is stuck in an infinite loop.  Please advise.  It is crazy because on my development server only one email is sent per account, but on my production server I received 5 emails.  Thus, meaning all users of my site received multiple emails.

Controller:

```
 class BatchEmailsController < ApplicationController

 before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!

 def deliver
 flash[:notice] = "Email Being Delivered"
 Delayed::Job.enqueue(BatchEmailJob.new(params[:batch_email_id]), 3, 10.seconds.from_now, :queue => 'batch-email', :attempts => 0)
 redirect_to admin_batch_emails_path
end
end
```

Job in the lib folder:

```
 class BatchEmailJob < Struct.new(:batch_email_id)
 def perform
 be = BatchEmail.find(batch_email_id)
 if be.to.eql?("Contractors")
   cs = Contractor.all
   cs.each do|c|
     begin
        BatchEmailMailer.batch_email(be.subject, be.message, be.link_name, be.link_path, be.to, c.id).deliver
     rescue Exception => e
          Rails.logger.warn "Batch Email Error: #{e.message}"
     end
 else
   ps = Painter.all
   ps.each do |p|
     begin
       BatchEmailMailer.batch_email(be.subject, be.message, be.link_name, be.link_path, be.to, p.id).deliver
     rescue Exception => e
       Rails.logger.warn "Batch Email Error: #{e.message}"
     end
   end
 end
 end
 end
```

Delayed Job Initializer:

```
 Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 0
```

**Please provide feedback on this approach. I want to send out the batch email to all users, but avoid retrying multiple times if something goes wrong.  I added rescue block to catch email exceptions in hope that the batch will skip errors and continue processing.  As a last resort do not run again if something else goes wrong.**

Comment: the job probably encountered an error somewhere which restarted the job.

Comment: jvnill, how can I prevent this from happening then and continuing to send emails? Based on what you said, I'm assuming this has something to do with a failed delivery.

Comment: you need to add flag on batch_emails which tracks if the email was already processed so that it will not be sent a second time.

Comment: Hi, couldn't I just add the following to an initializer: Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 1

Comment: yes that's also a possible solution. be warned that any emails that's supposed to be sent out after the email occurred wont be sent out

Comment: jvnill, please see updated question.. thinking a rescue block for each email being delivered

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25916/discussion-between-brian-and-jvnill)

Answer (score 2):

What one of my apps does which seems to work flawlessly after millions of emails:

1) in an initializer, do NOT let DelayedJob re-attempt a failed job AND ALSO not let DJ delete failed jobs:

```
Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false
Delayed::Worker.max_attempts = 1
```

2) Scheduling a mass email is 1 job, aka the "master job"

3) When THAT jobs runs, it spawns N jobs where N is the number of emails being sent. So each email gets its own job. (Note: if you use a production email service with 'batch' capability, one "email" might actually be a batch of 100 or 1000 emails.)

4) We have an admin panel that shows us if we have any failed jobs, and if they are, because we don't delete them, we can inspect the failed job and see what happened (malformed email address etc)

If one email fails, the others are un-affected. And no email can ever be sent twice.